# "406 Not Acceptable"

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a problem calling
this Api

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/v1alpha/accounts/{accountId}/mailboxes/{mailboxId}:disable",
    produces = { "application/problem+json" }
)
default ResponseEntity<Void> _disableMailbox(@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]{6}$") @Size(min=6,max=6) @ApiParam(value = "The unique 6 character internal id that represents the customer account.",required=true) @PathVariable("accountId") String accountId,@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$") @Size(min=36,max=36) @ApiParam(value = "The unique 36 character internal id that represents the mailbox.",required=true) @PathVariable("mailboxId") String mailboxId) throws Exception {
    return disableMailbox(accountId, mailboxId);
}
```

I always got :
ERROR :
`"406 Not Acceptable: [{\"type\":\"https://developers/error-handling\",\"title\":\"Not Acceptable\",\"status\":406,\"detail\":\"Could not find acceptable representation\"}]"`

I tried to change headers but it didn't work

headers

```
[Content-Type:"application/json", Accept:"application/json, text/plain, */*" ]
```

Comment: Why does the API even define what it produces if it doesn't return anything (`ResponseEntity<Void>`)?

Comment: I am really don't know , this API from another team @Thomas

Comment: What about adding `application/problem+json` to the `Accept`-header?

Comment: @dan1st I will try

Comment: @dan1st same problem

Comment: Why do you need the `produces = { "application/problem+json" }` anyways?